# multicols page break issue [solved]

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

I have the following, and I get a page break before the `multicols`. I have tried `\vfill\break` and `\break` before and after `multicols`. I have also tried `multicols*`.

Need to add `\vfill` before graph...

```
Graph the function
\[
f(x)=x^{3}.
\]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale=0.75,
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
        ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xlabel style={below right},
        ylabel style={above left},
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-5.5,
        ymax=5.5] 
    \addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {x^2}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\item \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale=0.75,
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
        ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xlabel style={below right},
        ylabel style={above left},
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-5.5,
        ymax=5.5] 
    \addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {x^3}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\item \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale=0.75,
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
        ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xlabel style={below right},
        ylabel style={above left},
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-5.5,
        ymax=5.5] 
    \addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {-x^2}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\item \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale=0.75,
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
        ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xlabel style={below right},
        ylabel style={above left},
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-5.5,
        ymax=5.5] 
    \addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {-x^3}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}\hfill\rule{0.2\columnwidth}{1pt}
```